# How can I find out in Java whether any file of a certain directory is open?

Tags: java

What is the best way in Java to find out whether any file of a certain directory (including subdirectories) is open? I'm not really sure whether "open" is the best expression for what I mean, I mean I cannot delete, rename or write that file because someone else has already "locked" it. Of course the solution should work independent of the operating system.

The reason why I need is because I have a Java Desktop-App (developed using Swing) which shall provide an auto-update feature. Therefore the app shall download a zip file from an HTTP server and try to unpack the zip to the app directory. At least under Windows that's not easily possible because the jar files of the app cannot be overwritten while the app itself is running. Therefore the update files will first be unzipped to a temp folder, the app will then be rerun in that temp folder and copies the contents of the temp folder to the app directory. After that the app will be rerun again in the app folder.

Now the problem: Before the contents of the temp folder are copied to the app folder it would be great to check whether all files in the app folder can potentially be overwritten. And that's why I have asked the question above. I know that even if such a check is possible it is not a 100% guarantee that the copy process will succeed, but at least would be a quite high chance that it will succeed.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the word "locked" instead of "opened"?

Comment: It depends on the file system. All major file system _except_ the common one used by the Microsoft Windows OS simply do not have this as a concept. Yes, there's such a thing as 'file is open', but you can delete, change, etc an opened file just fine. Hence, 'independent of operating system' is a bizarre rider here - __if__ you work on the presumption 'open file = can't delete', which doesn't hold across OSes.

Comment: The answer for this in Java is more than likely to .... not use Java. You'd be writing a native hook one way or another (JNI/JNA to access Windows' header files, or `flock`/other options on *nix). `nio` has `FileChannel` and consequently `FileLock`, but this won't necessarily be respected by the entire OS for every OS. Overall this reads like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/): why do you need to do this?

Comment: The File class has some methods which can provide a hint (canRead(), canWrite()), but as other said there is no fool proof way. The "best" way to deal with the possibility of files being locked or inaccessible due to user rights is to be reactive - proper error handling. Assume every file operation can fail.

Comment: Similar methods are present in `java.nio.file.Files`, those are `isWritable(Path)`, `isReadable(path)` and several more. Try them on windows…

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to find all open / locked files? Sounds a bit like a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I've added a little explanation of the reason for my question to the description.

Comment: I wouldn't really know exactly how to make one so I can't answer, but if you look at the most prolific Java application of all - Minecraft Java Edition, it uses a separate launcher application which will manage downloading and applying updates. To do such a thing in Java I guess it would involve writing a small wrapper application which can fork the actual main Java application as a new process. If you can start and stop the process programmatically you do not even have to worry about system resources being locked or not.

Comment: In fact, at least at one time, if the Minecraft launcher hit a locked file it couldn't delete, it would show an error to the user (usually along the lines of "Minecraft is currently running"). There's no need there for the check, you simply respond to the error conditions.